# Can I perform a Chi Square test comparing the one year mortality of my 160 patients versus the 108000 patients of a cohort in the litterature?

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have exactly zero experience with statistics.

I was interested in comparing 1 year mortality of patients $\ge$ 60 years old versus $<$ 60 in a cohort after a specific intervention.

I performed a Chi Square test that found a p-value of 0.28, so I couldn't reject H0 (1 year mortality is not different in patients $<$ 60 versus $\ge$ 60).

But the most exhaustive database of patients having undergone the same intervention finds a 1-year mortality lower than mine.

So I performed a Chi Square test on a contingency table comparing mortality in my cohort with that in the international database. It looked something like this.

[image: contingency table]

The calculated p-value was 0.0011.

Is this OK to reject the null hypothesis in this case? Is there a problem with the inadequacy between the two sample sizes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: (1) At the beginning of your Question you say "I performed a Chi Square test that found a p-value of 0.28, so I couldn't reject $H_0$ (1 year mortality is not different in patients < 60 versus ≥ 60)."  You do not show the data you used for that test, so I will not comment on it. (2) In the second part you mention a chi-squared test. I don't think that is an improper procedure, but do not consider it optimal, given your objectives. I include two other, possibly better, tests in my Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consider database as population.** If your table means that you had 40 deaths (within one year) out of 160 undergoing the intervention, then the simplest approach is to compare this with the proportion $\theta_0 = 0.16$ of deaths in the exhaustive database. This considers
that 100,000 patients in the large database are enough to use $\theta_0 = 0.16$
as a reference *probability* (rather than a sample proportion).

Then you can test the null hypothesis that for your group $H_0: \theta = 0.16$ against 
$H_a: \theta > 0.16.$ In R, the exact binomial test procedure is:

```
binom.test(40, 160, .16, alt="gr")

        Exact binomial test

data:  40 and 160
number of successes = 40, number of trials = 160, p-value = 0.002243
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.16
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1944176 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.25
```

There is strong evidence that your sample proportion significantly exceeds $\theta_0 = 0.16.$ First, the null hypothesis is rejected with the very small
P-value 0.0022. Second, the one-sided 95% CI for $(0.19, 1)$ for $\theta$ says the proportion
of fatalities in your group likely exceeds 0.19.

**Consider your results and database as two samples:** If you want to treat the database as a huge sample, then that is OK. The test is R shown below uses a normal approximation with continuity correction. The null hypothesis
is that the proportion $\theta_s$ in your study (estimated by $40/160)$ is the same as
the database proportion $\theta_d$ (estimated by $16,000/100,000),$ against
the alternative that your proportion is greater:

```
prop.test(c(40,16000), c(160, 100000), alt="gr")

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(40, 16000) out of c(160, 1e+05)
X-squared = 8.9629, df = 1, p-value = 0.001378
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.03053001 1.00000000
sample estimates:
  prop 1 prop 2 
    0.25   0.16
```

The null hypothesis is rejected with P-value 0.0014. The 95% CI in the
printout is for the difference $\theta_s - \theta_d.$ The difference
is likely above 0.03.

Below is output from Minitab's version of this test. This test handles the
normal approximation a little differently, but results are not much different
from those in the version above using R.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample      X       N  Sample p
1          40     160  0.250000
2       16000  100000  0.160000


Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.09
95% lower bound for difference:  0.0336600
Test for difference = 0 (vs > 0):  Z = 2.63  P-Value = 0.004
```

*Note:* The test statistic for a commonly used version of this test is based on the two
sample proportions $p_1 = X_1/n_1$ (here 0.25) and $p_2 = X_2/n_2$ (here 0.16)
as follows: $Z = \frac{p_1 - p_2}{SE},$ where 
$SE = \sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n_1} + \frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{n_2}},$ rejecting $H_0: \theta_1 = \theta_2$ in favor of $H_a: \theta_1 > \theta_2$ at the 5% level when $Z > 1.96.$ [Ref: Ott & Longnecker: *Statistical Methods and Data Analysis,* (various editions) section on differences between two population proportions.]

**Chi-squared test of homogeneity:** You could also do a chi-squared test of homogeneity (meaning that the proportion of fatalities is the same in your study as in the database). This is inherently
a two-sided test (because differences between observed counts and expected counts are squared), so you would have to interpret the direction of any difference
by looking at residuals. Because your objective is better expressed by a one-sided test, prefer the tests above to the chi-squared test.

The version of the chi-squared test shown here is without continuity correction,
and its P-value matches your result.

```
chisq.test(cbind(c(40,16000), c(160, 100000)), corr=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

 data:  cbind(c(40, 16000), c(160, 1e+05))
 X-squared = 6.4646, df = 1, p-value = 0.011
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful answer. Indeed it makes much more sense to consider the database as a population, but using your second approach may prevent some criticisms, as our sample was not drawn from the database. Thank you again

Comment: Just added formula for second approach.